# Strange exception in application

Tags: android, exception

I have recently put an application on the Market and I have received until now 7 errors that look like the following:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.ProgressBar$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x2. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

Can someone tell me how to debug the problem? What is `View` with id 0x2 - is there a way to find out?

Comment: Can you post your layout? It might be that you have two components with the same id.

Comment: It seems you may have two views with the same id value, double check your xml files.

Answer (score 3):

I've received this error under the following conditions - I'm replacing the icon of an item in the actionbar (in my case a throbber for a refresh button), and while it's in that state, I rotate the device.  This error arises from it trying to restore the view's saved state and noticing the difference between what's declared and what's serialized.

Comment: When I assign the new view to the menu item, I also declare:
`throbber.getActionView().setSaveEnabled(false);` (where `throbber` is of type `MenuItem`).  Then in the fragment's `onActivityCreated` method I test to see if the underlying task has exited and been handled. If it hasn't (i.e. the user is still waiting for feedback), I reinitialize the animated version with another call to `throbber.setActionView(getAnimatedRefreshImageView());`

`getAnimatedRefreshView` is a method I have to manage the ImageView so I don't tax the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a stacktrace next to the report which could help you find the exact line of code.